# LavaCharts - Exporting Chart as an Image - 'getImageCallBack is not defined'

Tags: charts

So I am using Kevin Hill's excellent PHP wrapper for Google Charts, 'LavaCharts' and am following his guide on how to access the image URI of each (I need to output the charts in an image format so that I can export the page as a PDF).

https://github.com/kevinkhill/lavacharts/wiki/Getting-a-chart-as-an-image-3.0.x

I am getting the following error: 'getImageCallBack is not defined'

[image]

I am registering the 'getImageCallBack' event on each chart from the Controller:

```
    \Lava::PieChart('TotalCallsReceived', $totalCallsReceived, [
        'events' => ['ready' => 'getImageCallBack'],
        'title' => 'Total Calls Received & Transferred',
        'is3D' => false,
    ]);
```

And then in the head of my page I have the following. (I will figure out what to do with the URI once I've solved this error. For now logging it is fine)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getImageCallback(event, chart) {
        console.log(chart.getImageURI());
        // This will return in the form of "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAUA..."
    }
</script>
```

Has anybody else overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the function names are different and need to match case...

the `"B"` is capitalized here...

`'events' => ['ready' => 'getImageCallBack'],`

and *not* here...

`function getImageCallback(event, chart) {`

Comment: Ah thanks. That's pretty embarrassing - what a rookie mistake!